# Clicks on top of html5 Video elements don't work in Safari on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, mobile, video, safari

Does anyone know how to get clicks to register on top of an html5 video element in Safari on an iPhone?

I've tried a number of techniques mentioned here on SO:

- no 'controls' attribute on the video element
- absolutely position my clickable elements on top of the video

Nothing seems to work. I don't see any click events, nor do I even see touchstart.  I've tried on iOS5 and iOS6.

I'd like to achieve something similar to Vimeo's mobile site.  They seem to absolutely position a button on top of their html5 player, and clicking it works.  I've looked at their source and I can't see anything special...yet their click handler works.

Here's a JSFiddle of a very simple example.  Tapping the blue button doesn't seem to fire a click event:

http://jsfiddle.net/5kLKg/

```
see JSFiddle
```

Comment: Should I be able to click on the button on Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Vimeo actually uses `display: none` on the video element.  I'm thinking that my original question might be impossible.

I updated my fiddle to use the Vimeo solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5kLKg/2/

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution? I can't hide the video in my case, as it's scrolling beneath a fixed position button, but it doesn't hide the entire video.

Comment: @WillshawMedia nope, unfortunately we had to go with the display: none solution.